# How can I respond to any exit (blur) of an input text element which contains a specified string in its ID?

Tags: jquery, blur, jshint

I want to update an input text element when any of a specific category (based on ID) of other input text elements are exited. Specifically, when any of the following input text elements:

```
boxAmount1
boxAmount2
boxAmount3
boxAmount4
boxAmount5
```

...are exited/blurred, I want to update the input text element which has "boxGrandTotal" in its ID.

I thought "contains" would help me, so tried this:

```
$(document).on("blur", '[id:contains('boxAmount')]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').text([combined values of all "boxAmount" input texts]);
});
```

...but JSHint tells me "Missing name in function declaration" on the first line, and "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" on the thrid and last line.

What do I need to do to respond to all "boxAmount" blurs?

**NOTE:** I use the "id$=" jazz because the IDs I give the elements (such as "boxGrandTotal") end up being mangled by Sharepoint, which prepends a bunch of gobbledygook to the IDs.

Comment: wait, you mean if the input contains value `boxAmount`?

Comment: No, the input texts have IDs that contain "boxAmount" (boxAmount1, boxAmount2, etc.)

Comment: Oh, in that case the current answer should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute [**starts with**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) or [**contains**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector

```
$(document).on("blur", '[id^="boxAmount"]', function (e) {

});
```

or

```
$(document).on("blur", '[id*="boxAmount"]', function (e) {

});
```